# WPF ListView.SelectedItems returns wrong item order if you "Shift-Select" from bottom to top

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selecteditem

I implemented some logic for the user to be able to copy selected values from a ListView to the clipboard. While playing playing around with it, I noticed that ListView.SelectedItems returns the items in a different order depending on how you shilft-select items.

For simplicity, let's assume my List has 5 items, each containing a string with a single number in ascending order, e.g. first item = "1", second item = "2", etc.

**Scenario 1:** Click on item 2, hold shift, click on item 4 -> SelectedItems has the expected order of elements "2,3,4".

**Scenario 2:** Click on item 4, hold shift, click on item 2 -> SelectedItems has an unexpected order of elements "4,2,3".

Am I missing something really simple here? If I select a range using shift "from the bottom to the top", the first item clicked is moved to the first position of SelectedItems, then following all the others in correct order.

Is the ListView noticing that the item previously selected is also within the range? So to say remembering it, leaving it at the first position in SelectedItems and just "adding" all the remaining items? Wouldn't bother me if you'd only shift-select from the top to bottom, but the other way around it messes up the order... :/

Any help/idea is appreciated!

Comment: Why does the order mater? Ordering, Sorting and whaterever Filtering you might still do on the UI level, should be done via the collection view anyway. And that would override whatever selection order there is.

Comment: Also, I hope you do use Primary Keys or something like that for he actuall value? If you just use a Index, you run into index race conditions (what used to be index 2, no longer is; what might not have been on the list, might now be index 2).

Comment: You simply can't rely on the item order in SelectedItems, except that SelectedItem is the first element in SelectedItems. What you observe seems obvious. A single click sets SelectedItem, selecting more adds them to the collection in an undefined order while keeping SelectedItem at index 0.

Comment: @Christopher: The order matters to me since it's logged data. So basically, I'd have to compare the result I'm getting to my current collection status and then re-order (taking into account the possible changes to the Collection)?  (at)Clemens: Yes... you're right.

Comment: Use primary keys or other reliable data to identify Elements. Relying on Indexes is a bad idea to begin with. If you rely on PK's (or something as unambigious as that) the order is irrelevant. Changes to the filters are irrelevant. The element is there and will be selected, or not there and nothing happens.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I will do as you said! Sadly, I can't upvote your comment (I assume it's because this account is too new).